# Spring Integration DSL: lambda to return a Message<T> in handle method, e.g. with DelegatingSessionFactory?

Tags: spring-integration-dsl

Motivation: I need to set the threadKey for a DelegatingSessionFactory before I route to an Sftp outbound gateway and unset the threadKey afterwards.

Depending on a tenant I need to use a different Sftp user account. The user accounts are a matter of configuration in my application.yml, I do not want to write separate routes for each new tenant.

```
public IntegrationFlow aDynamicSftpFlow() {
    f -> f
        .handle(tenantSessionDefine()) // how can I use a lambda instead?
        .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(delegatingSessionFactory, ...))
        .handle(...) // undefine sftp session
}
```

Setting the threadKey requires a `Message<?>`, not just payload and headers. So I use a bean because it takes a message:

```
public class TenantSessionDefine {


    private DelegatingSessionFactory delegatingSessionFactory;

    public TenantSessionDefine(DelegatingSessionFactory delegatingSessionFactory) {
        this.delegatingSessionFactory = delegatingSessionFactory;
    }

    public Message<?> defineSession(Message<?> message) {
        return delegatingSessionFactory.setThreadKey(message, message.getHeaders()
            .get("tenantId", String.class)); 
// used by SessionFactoryLocator
    }
}
```

I would like to write that as a lambda, as in

```
.handle(message -> delegatingSessionFactory.setThreadKey(message, 
    message.getPayload().getTenant())
```

but that is not so easy. The lambda that can be used with `handle()` which takes a `Message<T>` ends the flow because it is a void function (`MessageHandler` functional interface). The other lambda is a GenericHandler, which does not end the flow, but it takes payload and headers, not a message.

This is just an example, every now and then I wish I could use `handle()` with a message in a lambda without ending the flow. How can I do that?

**Update**

The `DelegatingSessionFactory` is not a particularly well suited example. Since setting and clearing the thread key should happen before and after the sftp invocation, an advice fits better than defining a handler before and after the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The javadoc for `handle()` says

> Use `handle(Class, GenericHandler)` if you need to access the entire message.

The Class parameter must be `Message.class`:

```
.handle(Message.class, 
    (message, headers) -> sftpSessionFactory
        .setThreadKey(message, headers.get("tenantId")))
```

Comment: Also, there is a setThreadKey/clearThreadKey pair which does not require a message. Besides, setting the thread key for the DelegatingSessionFactory is probably better done in an AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice, see update to the question.